# how to delete single cell of gridview at a time when click on related cell button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can I find the column index dynamically of selected Linkbutton when click on any of the link button which is created dynamically. All the buttons are created dynamically and also rows and columns are created dynamically in gridview. I need to Delete Individual Cell of gridview when click on related  Linkbutton.. So that I need to find column and Row Index.This screen shot gives an idea of the problem.

This Code is for creating Link button Dynamically where Columns are not fixed. and I Need to delete single cell when click on delete button of related Cell of gridview.

```
protected void gv_TT_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[2].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("colspan", "2");
        }
        int index = e.Row.RowIndex;
        int k = 0;
        GVdata = (DataTable)ViewState["GVdata"];
        GridViewTable = (DataTable)ViewState["GridViewTable"];

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GVdata.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            // ADD LINK BUTTON IF row.text != Empty(Blank)
            if (e.Row.Cells[i + 3].ToString() != "&nbsp;")
            {
                if (e.Row.Cells[i + 3].ToString() != " ")
                {
                    if (e.Row.Cells[i + 3].ToString() != string.Empty)
                    {
                        Label txt = new Label();

                        LinkButton lb1 = new LinkButton();
                        lb1.ID = k + "_" + (i + 3) + "Btn1";
                        lb1.Text = " Update ";
                        lb1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

                        LinkButton lb2 = new LinkButton();
                        lb2.ID = k + "_" + (i + 3) + "Btn2";
                        lb2.Text = " Delete ";
                        lb2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

                        lb1.CausesValidation = false;
                        lb1.Click += new EventHandler(Update_Click);
                        lb2.CausesValidation = false;
                        lb2.Click += new EventHandler(Delete_Click);

                        txt.Text = GridViewTable.Rows[index][i + 3].ToString();
                        e.Row.Cells[i + 3].Controls.Add(txt);
                        e.Row.Cells[i + 3].Controls.Add(lb1);
                        e.Row.Cells[i + 3].Controls.Add(lb2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        k++;
    }
}
```

[Click here for Screen Shot image output of Sample Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOZZ5.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOZZ5.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to delete a row from a grid.

In the GridView template:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="delRow" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "itemID").ToString() %>' />
```

And then in the `RowCommand` in code behind

```
    protected void gv_TT_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "delRow")
        {
            //get the id from the button and covert it
            int itemID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            //cast the viewstate as a datatable
            DataTable dt = ViewState["GridViewTable"] as DataTable;

            //filter out the row with the itemID to be deleted with Linq
            DataTable dtFiltered = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<int>("itemID") != itemID).CopyToDataTable();

            //set the viewstate with the filtered datatable
            ViewState["GridViewTable"] = dtFiltered;

            //rebind the grid
            GridView1.DataSource = dtFiltered;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Your problem however is the dynamic controls. When you add the dynamic control you have to add a `CommandName` and a `CommandArgument` to the button for it to work like the button in the snippet above:

```
    protected void gv_TT_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton lb1 = new LinkButton();
            lb1.ID = "Btn1";
            lb1.Text = "DeleteRow";
            lb1.CommandName = "delRow";
            //value cannot be assigned yet
            //lb1.CommandArgument = "";
            lb1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

            e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(lb1);
        }
    }
```

There is just one problem. In order to assign the `CommandArgument` we have to use the data from the GridView, but the data is not yet present in `RowCreated`. So we have to assign the value in the `RowDataBound` event:

```
    protected void gv_TT_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
            LinkButton lb1 = e.Row.FindControl("Btn1") as LinkButton;
            lb1.CommandArgument = drv["itemID"].ToString();
        }
    }
```